# How to mark highest volumes of the session in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot shape above the candle of highest volume on live chart. After-that if again a candle appear with higher than the previous volume, it will plot a shape above that candle too...but if the volume is lower than the previous highest volume, it will not plot any shape. And of course, the entire calculation starts with new session and ends with the session

In this way, it is obvious that the first volume is always the highest since there is no volume data of the previous, but that's okay with me. It will always mark the first volume as high.

I am new to pine-script, and I tried to do it myself but I don't find anything helpful that solve my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need a variable that will store the value of `volume` and update its value in 2 cases:

1. In case it's a new day - set it to `volume` of that bar (the opening bar of the new day).
2. In case it's not the first bar of the day, check if this is higher than the value of the current stored value, and if it is store the new `volume` (the higher one).

Since you need the variable to "remember" its value between executions of the script, you'll need to use the `var` keyword for that variable.

You can use 2 functions to help you:

1. `ta.change(time("D"))` will return `true` on the first bar of each day, regardless the timeframe you are using.
2. `math.max()` function will return the higher value between 2 values you'll set as arguments of the function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("highest daily volume")

var highest_volume = volume

if ta.change(time("D"))
    highest_volume := volume
else
    highest_volume := math.max(highest_volume, volume)

plot(highest_volume)
```

EDIT:

You clarified that you wish to plot a shape on the bar where the highest volume of the day is. I don't believe you can do it with `plotshape()` since you can't change its `x` value after plowing it. We can however use a label.

I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do that, but you can use an `array` of `label`s and change the `x` variable each time there is a change in the `highest_volume` variable:

```
//@version=5
indicator("highest daily volume", overlay = true)

var highest_volume = volume
var label_array = array.new_label(100000)

var index = 0

if ta.change(time("D"))
    highest_volume := volume
    array.set(label_array, index, label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(highest_volume)))
    index += 1
else
    highest_volume := math.max(highest_volume, volume)
    if highest_volume != highest_volume[1]
        label.set_x(array.get(label_array, index - 1), bar_index)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I think there are something wrong in my question explanation. I want to plot shape above the candle of highest volume on live chart. After-that if again a candle appear with higher than the previous volume, it will plot a shape above that candle too...but if the volume is lower than the previous highest volume, it will not plot any shape. And of course, the entire calculation starts with new session and ends with the session.